# Recompute Ember custom helper on change of a controller property that is passed to the helper

Tags: ember.js

I'm changing the value of a property in my controller and the helper fails to recompute them.

Sample code here:

My template looks like,

```
{{#if (my-helper info)}}
    <span>Warning</span>
{{/if}}
```

In my controller,

```
changeAction: function() {
    let that = this,
        info = that.get("info");
    set(info, "showWarning", true);
}
```

my helper,

```
import { helper as buildHelper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export default buildHelper(function(params) {
    let that = this,
        info = that.get("info");
    if(info.showWarning ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues with your code:

The template helper seems to get an object as it's first and only position param: `{{my-helper info}}` while `info` is `{ showWarning: true }`. A template helper does recompute if the value passed it changes but not if a property of that value changes. A quick fix would be `{{my-helper info.showWarning}}`.

In your template helper your are trying to access the property on it's `this` context. As far as I know that's not supported. As you are using a positional param and it's the first one, it's available as first entry in`params` array. So your template helper should look like:

```js
export default buildHelper(function([info]) {
    if(info.showWarning ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false
    }
});
```

What version of Ember are you using? If it's >= 3.1 you don't need to use `this.get()` in your controller. If you are using Ember < 3.1 you need to use `info.get()` also in template helper.

But as described before I would not recommend passing an object to a template helper as it's only updated if the object itself is replaced. Changing a property of it is not enough. You might be able to do so using [Class-based Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/#toc_class-based-helpers) but I wouldn't recommend to do so as it's error prune.

Comment: Thank you @jelhan. Actually this is a sample code, I want to monitor more than 5 values of the controller property "info". Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: If your template helper depends on that much input data, you might have a design issue. Maybe a component would better fit for your use case?